# Comparing a UILabel string to a mutable array in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string, compare, uilabel

There are a lot of posts similar to mine but the answers given are not working on my program. I read a lot of forums and blogs already. I am really having a hard time, please help me. My program has a string inputed by the user and will compare it to an array if it's the same or not.

code:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *aScreen;
IBOutlet UILabel *result;

NSMutableArray *b = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[b addObject: @"one"];
[b addObject: @"two"];
[b addObject: @"rawr"];

if([b containsObject:aScreen]){
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TRUE"];
} //this is my first trial.. there are no errors but it does not work the way I want it.
```

It should compare the string in the aScreen to the array b, then output "true" if it is equal in the 'result'. If I will input "one = one", the 'result' should show "true".

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a string to a label, but you should use its `text` property instead. Do the following:

```
if ([b containsObject: aScreen.text]) {
    result.text = @"TRUE";
}
```

Comment: Ha... I noticed that after I origionally posted my answer - and having assumed it didn't work for him I suggested the change. I think before your question edit the UILabel declaration wasn't in the `code` block. Nice spot.

Comment: Out of curiosity - they must have added logic for that case, huh? (Where the item in the array and the object being compared are both `NSString`s) They don't specifically mention it in the documentation - which I find odd.

Comment: @Steve The NSArray docs state that `isEqual:` is used for object comparison. I'm sure that `-[NSString isEqual:]` calls `isEqualToString:` with extra checks. That's why they say the latter is faster.